# Swift Repeat While Loop Best Practices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have some Asynchronous network calls in my project. In a segue to another VC, I check whether the value of the dataModel (for the next VC) is nil continously using repeat while, ie:

```
 repeat{
   print("not yet")
   } while DataModel == nil
```

Is this a bad practice/ "hacky" approach?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's a horrible practice. Use a completion handler which is called when the asynchronous task has finished.

Comment: Thats what I thought, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Using the completionHandler, I still have the problem that a segue might trigger by the user before data has been loaded. So within the segue, how would I await completion?

Comment: Perform the segue *manually* in the completion handler.

Comment: I'm trying to load the data before the segue is called (in order to reduce loading time). Should I instead load the data right when the segue is called?

Comment: You have 2 options. 1/ As @vadian said, perform the segue *manually* inside the completion handler. You will need to remove the segue of the button(or whatever) in the storyboard, and then replace it by using **@IBAction**, handle the segue in that **@IBAction** function. 2/ Perform the Asynchronous network call in the next view that segue perform, in **viewDidLoad** of that next view, reload the data of UIs inside the completion handler